# Using stored procedure in Entity Framework 5 with complex type?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-5

I have the following stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FullTextSearchOnContent]
(
    @SearchText NVARCHAR(200),
    @LanguageId INT ,
    @ContentStatusId INT ,
    @ResultCount INT 
)
AS

BEGIN
    SET FMTONLY OFF;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF (@SearchText IS NULL) OR (@SearchText = '') OR (@ResultCount IS NULL) OR (@ResultCount = 0) RETURN NULL;
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP(@ResultCount) 
        C.Id AS ContentId, C.ImagePath AS ContentImagePath, C.IsSpecial,C.LanguageId,C.LockCommenting,C.RegistrationDate AS ContentRegistrationDate,C.StatusId AS ContentStatusId,C.Summary,C.Title,C.VisitNumber,C.AllTagsString,
        CS.FarsiName AS ContentStatusFarsiName,
        U.Id As UserId,U.InitialReputation AS UserInitialReputation,U.IsAdmin AS IsUserAdmin,U.FullName AS UserFullName,U.PhotoPath AS UserPhotoPath,U.RoleId AS UserRoleId,U.UserStatusId AS UserStatusId
        --,T.Id AS TagId, T.Name AS TagName
        FROM Content AS C
    INNER JOIN [User] AS U ON U.Id = C.WriterId
    INNER JOIN [Subject] AS S ON S.Id = C.SubjectId
    INNER JOIN [ContentStatus] AS CS ON CS.Id = C.StatusId
    --INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Tag AS T
    --          INNER JOIN TagContent AS TC ON TC.TagId=T.Id) 
    --          AS T ON T.ContentId = C.Id
    WHERE C.LanguageId = @LanguageId AND C.StatusId=@ContentStatusId AND CONTAINS((C.Title,C.AllTagsString),@SearchText) ORDER BY C.RegistrationDate DESC
END
```

It's used for fulltext search on some columns.

I want to use it in EF5, but it always returns `int`!

How can I use it in Entity Framework 5 ?

**EDIT :**

I couldn't generate the comlex type, whenever I click on `Get Column Information` button nothing happen !

[image: Get stored procedure information in entity framework 5]

Comment: how did you generate the `Complex Type`? can include in your question?

Comment: did you try to `Get Column Information`? if so, how it's look like?

Comment: As I described in Edit section, whenever I click on `Get Column Information` button nothing happen !

Comment: my apologize, i did not notice, try to remove your `complex type`, `stored procedure`, `function imports` or related from that `FullTextSearchOnContent` from your Model Browser and `update your model from database` again

Comment: I've done it, and imported the stored procedure again, but nothing changed

Comment: try to check your query, try to remove the `if statement` check it again,.

Comment: I've done it, nothing changed ! :-(

Comment: Try without the `TOP(@ResultCount) ` clause. It probably causes zero results.

Comment: I've tested it, when I changed the stored procedure to `SELECT TOP(@ResultCount) * from Content order by RegistrationDate desc` it worked bu when I add the inner join it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found The answer.
I've changed the stored procedure as the following :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FullTextSearchOnContent]
(
    @SearchText NVARCHAR(200),
    @LanguageId INT ,
    @ContentStatusId INT ,
    @ResultCount INT 
)
AS

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @ReturnTable table 
    (
        ContentId int not null,
        LanguageId int null,
        ContentStatusId int null,
        ContentTitle nvarchar(2000) null,
        ContentSummary nvarchar(2000) null,
        ContentImagePath nvarchar(50) null,
        IsSpecial bit null,
        LockCommenting bit null,
        VisitNumber int null,
        AllTagsString nvarchar(max) null,
        ContentRegistrationDate datetime not null,
        ContentStatusFarsiName nvarchar(50) null,
        UserId int null,
        UserInitialReputation int null,
        IsUserAdmin bit null,
        UserFullName nvarchar(71) null,
        UserPhotoPath nvarchar(50) null,
        UserRoleId int null,
        UserStatusId int null,
        SubjectId int not null,
        SubjectName nvarchar(50) null,
        SubjectSymbolPath nvarchar(1000) null
    )
    IF (@SearchText IS NULL) OR (@SearchText = '') OR (@ResultCount IS NULL) OR (@ResultCount = 0) RETURN NULL;
    INSERT @ReturnTable 
        SELECT DISTINCT TOP(@ResultCount) 
            C.Id AS ContentId, 
            C.LanguageId,
            C.StatusId AS ContentStatusId,
            C.Title AS ContentTitle,
            C.Summary AS ContentSummary,
            C.ImagePath AS ContentImagePath, 
            C.IsSpecial,
            C.LockCommenting,
            C.VisitNumber,
            C.AllTagsString,
            C.RegistrationDate AS ContentRegistrationDate,
            CS.FarsiName AS ContentStatusFarsiName,
            U.Id As UserId,
            U.InitialReputation AS UserInitialReputation,
            U.IsAdmin AS IsUserAdmin,
            U.FullName AS UserFullName,
            U.PhotoPath AS UserPhotoPath,
            U.RoleId AS UserRoleId,
            U.UserStatusId AS UserStatusId,
            S.Id AS SubjectId,
            S.Name AS SubjectName, 
            S.SymbolPath AS SubjectSymbolPath
            --,T.Id AS TagId, T.Name AS TagName
            FROM Content AS C
        INNER JOIN [User] AS U ON U.Id = C.WriterId
        INNER JOIN [Subject] AS S ON S.Id = C.SubjectId
        INNER JOIN [ContentStatus] AS CS ON CS.Id = C.StatusId
        --INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Tag AS T
        --          INNER JOIN TagContent AS TC ON TC.TagId=T.Id) 
        --          AS T ON T.ContentId = C.Id
        WHERE C.LanguageId = @LanguageId AND C.StatusId=@ContentStatusId AND CONTAINS((C.Title,C.AllTagsString),@SearchText) ORDER BY C.RegistrationDate DESC
    select * from @ReturnTable
    --SELECT TOP(@ResultCount) * from Content order by RegistrationDate desc
END
```

Now it works like a charm :-)

Comment: Looking good - just for the sake of completeness, here's some info what happens if VS tries to get column information: [Whats happening here behind the scenes?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13309133/1016343)