# Working with stored procedures in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

We have a person search stored procedure in our database, which I want to map into Visual Studio 2012 in my `edmx` file. The stored procedure returns the rows that satisfy the search and it sets a return code. When I execute the stored procedure manually I get the 4 rows I expect and I get a return code of 0.

I am using 2012, EF 5, and Entity Framework components in the framework.

When I select the stored procedure via `UpdateModelFromDatabase` and add it to my project, instead of defining the usual `{storedProcedureName}_Result` and returning that, it is translated to return only an integer. This prevents me from using the stored procedure to actually get to the rows to display them.

Interestingly enough, we have a test `PersonSearch` stored procedure which happens to be broken, but it is the same stored procedure with some internal changes. It still returns the results of the search AND sets the return code. When I pull that second stored procedure in, it does as expected and creates the stored procedure as returning the `{storedProcedureName}_Result` and returning the rows.

Has anyone seen this issue and how do I work around this issue? I need this first stored procedure to return the rows, not the return code.

***Follow Up***

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545698/using-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-5-with-complex-type) and had my DBA look at it.  But making similar changes to our stored procedure still has EF returning an integer instead of a complex object.
I also ran the sproc with all fields null and it returned the empty table structure in addition to the return code.

This is the stored procedure:

```
USE [ourdatabase]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_Person_SearchPerson]    Script Date:   01/30/2013 11:46:31 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Person_SearchPerson]

@firstName nvarchar(50), --OR
@lastName nvarchar(50), --OR
@companyName nvarchar(150), --OR
@phoneNumber1 nvarchar(50), --OR
@phoneNumber2 nvarchar(50), --OR
@email nvarchar(100), --OR
@franchiseSetId uniqueidentifier, --AND
@recordSourceId uniqueidentifier --AND
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @ReturnTable TABLE 
(
    PersonID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
    FirstName NVARCHAR(50), 
    LastName NVARCHAR(50),
    CompanyName NVARCHAR(150),
    EmailAddress NVARCHAR(100),
    PhoneNumber1 NVARCHAR(50),
    PhoneNumber2 NVARCHAR(50),
    Address1 NVARCHAR(50),
    City NVARCHAR(100),
    State NVARCHAR(50),
    PostalCode NVARCHAR(20),
    Score INT
)

-- flags to be used instead of calling the function udf_Strings_IsNullOrEmpty repeatedly
Declare
   @firstNamebit bit, --OR
   @lastNamebit bit, --OR
   @companyNamebit bit, --OR
   @phoneNumber1bit bit, --OR
   @phoneNumber2bit bit, --OR
   @emailbit bit, --OR
   @franchiseSetIdbit bit, --AND
   @recordSourceIdbit bit,
   @rowID int 

Insert into AppToolData..SearchLog 
(
   firstname ,
   lastname ,
   companyName ,
   phoneNumber1 ,
   phoneNumber2 ,
   email ,
   franchiseSetId ,
   recordSourceID ,
   StartTime_UTC
)
Values
(
   @firstname ,
   @lastname ,
   @companyName ,
   @phoneNumber1 ,
   @phoneNumber2 ,
   @email ,
   @franchiseSetId ,
   @recordSourceID ,
   SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
 )

Select @rowID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()



-- working set to accumulate Person records meeting search criteria
--Declare #People table
Create Table #People
(
   PersonID uniqueIdentifier 
)

--work set of distinct person reocrds from previous working set
Declare @DistinctPeople table
(
   PersonID uniqueIdentifier not null Primary Key
)

--Set flags
Select -- 0 = False (Is Not Null)  1 = True (Is Null)
   @firstNamebit = dbo.udf_Strings_IsNullOrEmpty(@firstName),
   @lastNamebit = dbo.udf_Strings_IsNullOrEmpty(@lastName),
   @companyNamebit = dbo.udf_Strings_IsNullOrEmpty(@companyName),
   @phoneNumber1bit = dbo.udf_Strings_IsNullOrEmpty(@phoneNumber1),
   @phoneNumber2bit = dbo.udf_Strings_IsNullOrEmpty(@phoneNumber2),
   @emailbit = dbo.udf_Strings_IsNullOrEmpty(@email)

DECLARE @MinimumWeight INT
SET @MinimumWeight = 1

DECLARE @AvailableWeight INT
SET @AvailableWeight = 0

If @franchiseSetId is not null
Begin
    Select @firstName = '%'+@firstName+'%'
    Select @lastName = '%'+@lastName+'%'
End
Else
Begin
    Select @firstName = @firstName+'%'
    Select @lastName = @lastName+'%'
End 



If @franchiseSetId is null
    Begin
      -- first name provided, last name not provided, phone number not provided
       IF @firstNamebit = 0 and @lastNamebit = 1 and @phoneNumber1bit = 1
           BEGIN
               SET @AvailableWeight = @AvailableWeight + 15  -- (First Name = 15, Last Name = 20, Phone Number = 30)

               -- Add records where first name is a partial string match
               Insert into #People
               Select PersonID from Person p
               Where (PatIndex(@firstName, p.FirstName)>0)
                   AND 
                   (
                      p.RecordSourceId = Coalesce(@recordSourceId, p.RecordSourceId)
                      --(@recordSourceId IS NULL) 
                      --OR
                      --(p.RecordSourceId = @recordSourceId)
                   )
                   AND 
                   (
                      p.FranchiseSetId = Coalesce(@franchiseSetId, p.FranchiseSetId)
                      --(@franchiseSetId IS NULL AND p.FranchiseSetId IS NULL) 
                      --OR
                      --(p.FranchiseSetId = @franchiseSetId)
                   )
           END
       -- first name not provided, last name provided, phone number not provided
       Else IF @firstNamebit = 1 and @lastNamebit = 0 and @phoneNumber1bit = 1
           BEGIN
               SET @AvailableWeight = @AvailableWeight + 20 -- (First Name = 15, Last Name = 20, Phone Number = 30)

               -- Add records where last name is a partial string match
               Insert into #People
               Select PersonID from Person p
               Where 
                   (PatIndex(@lastName, p.lastName)>0)
                   AND 
                   (
                      p.RecordSourceId = Coalesce(@recordSourceId, p.RecordSourceId)
                      --(@recordSourceId IS NULL) 
                      --OR
                      --(p.RecordSourceId = @recordSourceId)
                   )
                   AND 
                   (
                      p.FranchiseSetId = Coalesce(@franchiseSetId, p.FranchiseSetId)
                      --(@franchiseSetId IS NULL AND p.FranchiseSetId IS NULL) 
                      --OR
                      --(p.FranchiseSetId = @franchiseSetId)
                   )
           END
       -- first name provided, last name provided, phone number not provided
       Else IF @firstNamebit = 0 and @lastNamebit = 0 and @phoneNumber1bit = 1
           BEGIN
               SET @AvailableWeight = @AvailableWeight + 30 -- (First Name = 15, Last Name = 20, Phone Number = 30)

               -- Add records where first & last name are a partial string match
               Insert into #People
               Select PersonID from Person p
               Where 
                   (
                      (PatIndex(@firstName, p.FirstName)>0)
                      and
                      (PatIndex(@lastName, p.lastName)>0)
                   )
                   AND 
                   (
                      p.RecordSourceId = Coalesce(@recordSourceId, p.RecordSourceId)
                      --(@recordSourceId IS NULL) 
                      --OR
                      --(p.RecordSourceId = @recordSourceId)
                   )
                   AND 
                   (
                      p.FranchiseSetId = Coalesce(@franchiseSetId, p.FranchiseSetId)
                      --(@franchiseSetId IS NULL AND p.FranchiseSetId IS NULL) 
                      --OR
                      --(p.FranchiseSetId = @franchiseSetId)
                   )
           END
       -- first name provided, last name not provided, phone number provided
       IF @firstNamebit = 0 and @lastNamebit = 1 and @phoneNumber1bit = 0
           BEGIN
               SET @AvailableWeight = @AvailableWeight + 45 -- (First Name = 15, Last Name = 20, Phone Number = 30)

                   -- Add records where first name is a partial string match
                   --   and Phone Number is an exact match 
                   Insert into #People
               SELECT  
                p.PersonId
               FROM 
               Person p WITH (NOLOCK) 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN 
               PersonPhoneNumber ppn1 WITH (NOLOCK) 
                   ON p.PersonId=ppn1.PersonId
               LEFT OUTER JOIN 
               PhoneNumber pn1 WITH (NOLOCK) 
                   ON ppn1.PhoneNumberId=pn1.PhoneNumberId
               Where
                   (PatIndex(@firstName, p.FirstName)>0)
                   and 
                   pn1.Number = @PhoneNumber1
                   AND 
                   (
                      p.RecordSourceId = Coalesce(@recordSourceId, p.RecordSourceId)
                      --(@recordSourceId IS NULL) 
                      --OR
                      --(p.RecordSourceId = @recordSourceId)
                   )
                   AND 
                   (
                      p.FranchiseSetId = Coalesce(@franchiseSetId, p.FranchiseSetId)
                      --(@franchiseSetId IS NULL AND p.FranchiseSetId IS NULL) 
                      --OR
                      --(p.FranchiseSetId = @franchiseSetId)
                   )

           END
       -- first name not provided, last name provided, phone number provided
       Else IF @firstNamebit = 1 and @lastNamebit = 0 and @phoneNumber1bit = 0
           BEGIN
               SET @AvailableWeight = @AvailableWeight + 50 -- (First Name = 15, Last Name = 20, Phone Number = 30)

               -- Add records where last name is a partial string match
                   --   and Phone Number is an exact match 
                   Insert into #People
               SELECT  
                p.PersonId
               FROM 
               Person p WITH (NOLOCK) 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN 
               PersonPhoneNumber ppn1 WITH (NOLOCK) 
                   ON p.PersonId=ppn1.PersonId
               LEFT OUTER JOIN 
               PhoneNumber pn1 WITH (NOLOCK) 
                   ON ppn1.PhoneNumberId=pn1.PhoneNumberId
               Where
                   (PatIndex(@lastName, p.LastName)>0)
                   and 
                   pn1.Number = @PhoneNumber1
                   AND 
                   (
                      p.RecordSourceId = Coalesce(@recordSourceId, p.RecordSourceId)
                      --(@recordSourceId IS NULL) 
                      --OR
                      --(p.RecordSourceId = @recordSourceId)
                   )
                   AND 
                   (
                      p.FranchiseSetId = Coalesce(@franchiseSetId, p.FranchiseSetId)
                      --(@franchiseSetId IS NULL AND p.FranchiseSetId IS NULL) 
                      --OR
                      --(p.FranchiseSetId = @franchiseSetId)
                   )


           END
       -- first name provided, last name provided, phone number provided
       Else IF @firstNamebit = 0 and @lastNamebit = 0 and @phoneNumber1bit = 0
           BEGIN
               SET @AvailableWeight = @AvailableWeight + 65 -- (First Name = 15, Last Name = 20, Phone Number = 30)

               -- Add records where first & last name are a partial string match
                   --   and Phone Number is an exact match 
                   Insert into #People
               SELECT  
                p.PersonId
               FROM 
               Person p WITH (NOLOCK) 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN 
               PersonPhoneNumber ppn1 WITH (NOLOCK) 
                   ON p.PersonId=ppn1.PersonId
               LEFT OUTER JOIN 
               PhoneNumber pn1 WITH (NOLOCK) 
                   ON ppn1.PhoneNumberId=pn1.PhoneNumberId
               Where
                   (
                      (PatIndex(@firstName, p.FirstName)>0)
                      and 
                      (PatIndex(@lastName, p.LastName)>0)
                   )
                   and 
                   pn1.Number = @PhoneNumber1
                   AND 
                   (
                      p.RecordSourceId = Coalesce(@recordSourceId, p.RecordSourceId)
                      --(@recordSourceId IS NULL) 
                      --OR
                      --(p.RecordSourceId = @recordSourceId)
                   )
                   AND 
                   (
                      p.FranchiseSetId = Coalesce(@franchiseSetId, p.FranchiseSetId)
                      --(@franchiseSetId IS NULL AND p.FranchiseSetId IS NULL) 
                      --OR
                      --(p.FranchiseSetId = @franchiseSetId)
                   )


           END
       -- first name not provided, last name not provided, phone number provided
       Else IF @firstNamebit = 1 and @lastNamebit = 1 and @phoneNumber1bit = 0
           BEGIN
               SET @AvailableWeight = @AvailableWeight + 30  -- (First Name = 15, Last Name = 20, Phone Number = 30)

               -- Add records where Phone Number is an exact match 
                   Insert into #People
               SELECT  
                p.PersonId
               FROM 
               Person p WITH (NOLOCK) 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN 
               PersonPhoneNumber ppn1 WITH (NOLOCK) 
                   ON p.PersonId=ppn1.PersonId
               LEFT OUTER JOIN 
               PhoneNumber pn1 WITH (NOLOCK) 
                   ON ppn1.PhoneNumberId=pn1.PhoneNumberId
               Where
                   pn1.Number = @PhoneNumber1
                   AND 
                   (
                      p.RecordSourceId = Coalesce(@recordSourceId, p.RecordSourceId)
                      --(@recordSourceId IS NULL) 
                      --OR
                      --(p.RecordSourceId = @recordSourceId)
                   )
                   AND 
                   (
                      p.FranchiseSetId = Coalesce(@franchiseSetId, p.FranchiseSetId)
                      --(@franchiseSetId IS NULL AND p.FranchiseSetId IS NULL) 
                      --OR
                      --(p.FranchiseSetId = @franchiseSetId)
                   )


           END
    End
Else  -- Indicates WORKCENTER/Drybook search
    Begin
      IF @firstNamebit = 0
           BEGIN
               SET @AvailableWeight = @AvailableWeight + 15

               -- Add records where first name is a partial string match
               Insert into #People
               Select PersonID from Person p
               Where (PatIndex(@firstName, p.FirstName)>0)
                   AND 
                   (
                      p.RecordSourceId = Coalesce(@recordSourceId, p.RecordSourceId)
                      --(@recordSourceId IS NULL) 
                      --OR
                      --(p.RecordSourceId = @recordSourceId)
                   )
                   AND 
                   (
                      p.FranchiseSetId = Coalesce(@franchiseSetId, p.FranchiseSetId)
                      --(@franchiseSetId IS NULL AND p.FranchiseSetId IS NULL) 
                      --OR
                      --(p.FranchiseSetId = @franchiseSetId)
                   )
           END

      IF @lastNamebit = 0
           BEGIN
               SET @AvailableWeight = @AvailableWeight + 20

               -- Add records where last name is a partial string match
               Insert into #People
               Select PersonID from Person p
               Where 
                   (PatIndex(@lastName, p.lastName)>0)
                   AND 
                   (
                      p.RecordSourceId = Coalesce(@recordSourceId, p.RecordSourceId)
                      --(@recordSourceId IS NULL) 
                      --OR
                      --(p.RecordSourceId = @recordSourceId)
                   )
                   AND 
                   (
                      p.FranchiseSetId = Coalesce(@franchiseSetId, p.FranchiseSetId)
                      --(@franchiseSetId IS NULL AND p.FranchiseSetId IS NULL) 
                      --OR
                      --(p.FranchiseSetId = @franchiseSetId)
                   )
           END
    IF @phoneNumber1bit = 0
           BEGIN
               SET @AvailableWeight = @AvailableWeight + 30

               -- Add records where Phone Number 1 is an exact match
               Insert into #People
               SELECT  
             p.PersonId
               FROM 
               Person p WITH (NOLOCK) 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN 
               PersonPhoneNumber ppn1 WITH (NOLOCK) 
                   ON p.PersonId=ppn1.PersonId
               LEFT OUTER JOIN 
               PhoneNumber pn1 WITH (NOLOCK) 
                   ON ppn1.PhoneNumberId=pn1.PhoneNumberId
               Where pn1.Number = @PhoneNumber1
                   AND 
                   (
                      p.RecordSourceId = Coalesce(@recordSourceId, p.RecordSourceId)
                      --(@recordSourceId IS NULL) 
                      --OR
                      --(p.RecordSourceId = @recordSourceId)
                   )
                   AND 
                   (
                      p.FranchiseSetId = Coalesce(@franchiseSetId, p.FranchiseSetId)
                      --(@franchiseSetId IS NULL AND p.FranchiseSetId IS NULL) 
                      --OR
                      --(p.FranchiseSetId = @franchiseSetId)
                   )
           END
    End




IF @phoneNumber2bit = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @AvailableWeight = @AvailableWeight + 30

        -- Add records where Phone Number 2 is an exact match
        Insert into #People
        SELECT  
           p.PersonId
        FROM 
        Person p WITH (NOLOCK) 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        PersonPhoneNumber ppn1 WITH (NOLOCK) 
            ON p.PersonId=ppn1.PersonId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        PhoneNumber pn1 WITH (NOLOCK) 
            ON ppn1.PhoneNumberId=pn1.PhoneNumberId
        Where pn1.Number = @PhoneNumber2
            AND 
           (
              p.RecordSourceId = Coalesce(@recordSourceId, p.RecordSourceId)
              --(@recordSourceId IS NULL) 
              --OR
              --(p.RecordSourceId = @recordSourceId)
           )
           AND 
           (
              p.FranchiseSetId = Coalesce(@franchiseSetId, p.FranchiseSetId)
              --(@franchiseSetId IS NULL AND p.FranchiseSetId IS NULL) 
              --OR
              --(p.FranchiseSetId = @franchiseSetId)
           )
    END     

IF @emailbit = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @AvailableWeight = @AvailableWeight + 40

        -- Add records where Email is an exact match
         Insert into #People
         Select 
            p.PersonId
         from Person p
         LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         PersonEmailAddress pea WITH (NOLOCK) 
            ON p.PersonId=pea.PersonId
         LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         EmailAddress ea WITH (NOLOCK) 
            ON pea.EmailAddressId=ea.EmailAddressId
         Where ea.[Address] = @email
            AND 
               (
                  p.RecordSourceId = Coalesce(@recordSourceId, p.RecordSourceId)
                  --(@recordSourceId IS NULL) 
                  --OR
                  --(p.RecordSourceId = @recordSourceId)
               )
               AND 
               (
                  p.FranchiseSetId = Coalesce(@franchiseSetId, p.FranchiseSetId)
                  --(@franchiseSetId IS NULL AND p.FranchiseSetId IS NULL) 
                  --OR
                  --(p.FranchiseSetId = @franchiseSetId)
               )
    END

IF @companyNamebit = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @AvailableWeight = @AvailableWeight + 10

        -- Add records where Company Name is an exact match
         Insert into #People
         Select 
            p.PersonId
         from Person p
         LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         Company c WITH (NOLOCK) 
            ON p.CompanyId=c.CompanyId
         Where c.Name = @companyName
            AND 
               (
                  p.RecordSourceId = Coalesce(@recordSourceId, p.RecordSourceId)
                  --(@recordSourceId IS NULL) 
                  --OR
                  --(p.RecordSourceId = @recordSourceId)
               )
               AND 
               (
                  p.FranchiseSetId = Coalesce(@franchiseSetId, p.FranchiseSetId)
                  --(@franchiseSetId IS NULL AND p.FranchiseSetId IS NULL) 
                  --OR
                  --(p.FranchiseSetId = @franchiseSetId)
               )
    END

If @franchiseSetId is not null
Begin
    -- WORKCENTER -- do not return results that are less than a 40% match of what was passed in
    SET @MinimumWeight = @AvailableWeight * 0.4
End
Else
Begin
    -- ClaimsEntry -- do not return results that are less than a 60% match of what was passed in
    SET @MinimumWeight = @AvailableWeight * 0.6
End

-- get list of unique records
Insert into @DistinctPeople
Select Distinct PersonID from #People order by PersonID


INSERT INTO @ReturnTable (PersonID, FirstName, LastName, CompanyName, EmailAddress, PhoneNumber1, PhoneNumber2, Score)
(
SELECT 
    DistinctPeople.PersonId,
    p.FirstName,
    p.LastName,
    c.Name,
    ea.[Address],
    null as PhoneNumber1,
    null as PhoneNumber2,
    Score = 
    (
        --first name score
        (
            (CASE WHEN @firstNamebit = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            *
            (CASE WHEN PatIndex(@firstName, p.FirstName)>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            * 
            15
        )
        +
        --last name score
        (
            (CASE WHEN @lastNamebit = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            *
            (CASE WHEN PatIndex(@lastName, p.LastName)>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            * 
            20
        )
        +
        --email score
        (
            (CASE WHEN @emailbit = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            *
            (CASE WHEN ea.[Address] = @email THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            *
            40
        )
        +
        --company score
        (
            (CASE WHEN @companyNamebit = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            *
            (CASE WHEN PatIndex(@companyName, c.Name)>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            * 
            10
        )
    )
FROM
@DistinctPeople DistinctPeople
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
Person p WITH (NOLOCK) 
   ON DistinctPeople.PersonId=p.PersonId
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
PersonEmailAddress pea WITH (NOLOCK) 
   ON p.PersonId=pea.PersonId
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
EmailAddress ea WITH (NOLOCK) 
   ON pea.EmailAddressId=ea.EmailAddressId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Company c WITH (NOLOCK) 
   ON p.CompanyId=c.CompanyId
)


--If neither Phone number was passed as a parameter, the scores will not change
--   We can get rid of records that will not be returned
If @phoneNumber1bit = 1 and @phoneNumber2bit = 1
Begin
      -- update the phone number scores, the actual phone number values 
      --     can be in either the first or second position
       UPDATE rt 
       SET Score = Score +
               (
                   (CASE WHEN @phoneNumber1bit = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                   *
                   (CASE WHEN rt.PhoneNumber1 = @phoneNumber1 THEN 1 
                    WHEN rt.PhoneNumber2 = @phoneNumber1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                   *
                   30
               )
               +
               --phone 2 score
               (
                   (CASE WHEN @phoneNumber2bit = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                   *
                   (CASE WHEN rt.PhoneNumber1 = @phoneNumber2 THEN 1 
                    WHEN rt.PhoneNumber2 = @phoneNumber2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                   *
                   30
               )
       FROM @ReturnTable rt

      -- clear out the records we no longer care about
      DELETE FROM @ReturnTable WHERE  Score < @MinimumWeight
End

UPDATE rt 
SET rt.PhoneNumber1 =
(
    select top 1 xpn1.number 
    from PersonPhoneNumber xppn1 WITH (NOLOCK)  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  
    PhoneNumber xpn1 WITH (NOLOCK) 
      on xppn1.PhoneNumberId =xpn1.PhoneNumberId
    where xppn1.PersonId = rt.PersonID
    order by (CASE 
                WHEN xpn1.Number = @phoneNumber1 then -999 
                  else xppn1.SequenceNumber 
              end )
)
FROM @ReturnTable rt

UPDATE rt 
SET rt.PhoneNumber2 =
(
    select top 1 xpn1.number from PersonPhoneNumber xppn1 WITH (NOLOCK)  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  PhoneNumber xpn1 WITH (NOLOCK) on xppn1.PhoneNumberId =xpn1.PhoneNumberId
    where xppn1.PersonId = rt.PersonID
    and rt.PhoneNumber1 != xpn1.Number
            order by (CASE 
                    WHEN xpn1.Number = @phoneNumber2 then -998 
                  else xppn1.SequenceNumber end )
)
FROM @ReturnTable rt

-- update the phone number scores, the actual phone number values can be in either the first or second position
UPDATE rt 
SET Score = Score +
        (
            (CASE WHEN @phoneNumber1bit = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            *
            (CASE WHEN rt.PhoneNumber1 = @phoneNumber1 THEN 1 
                  WHEN rt.PhoneNumber2 = @phoneNumber1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            *
            30
        )
        +
        --phone 2 score
        (
            (CASE WHEN @phoneNumber2bit = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            *
            (CASE WHEN rt.PhoneNumber1 = @phoneNumber2 THEN 1 
                  WHEN rt.PhoneNumber2 = @phoneNumber2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            *
            30
        )
FROM @ReturnTable rt

-- clear out the records we no longer care about
DELETE FROM @ReturnTable WHERE  Score < @MinimumWeight

UPDATE rt 
SET Address1 = a.Address1,
    City = a.City,
    State = s.Abbreviation,
    PostalCode = a.PostalCode
FROM @ReturnTable rt
OUTER APPLY
    (
    SELECT  TOP 1 *
    FROM    PersonAddress pa WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE   pa.PersonId = rt.PersonID
    ORDER BY pa.SequenceNumber
    ) ppa
LEFT JOIN Address a WITH (NOLOCK) on ppa.AddressId = a.AddressId
LEFT JOIN State s WITH (NOLOCK) on a.StateId = s.StateId


Update  AppToolData..SearchLog 
   Set EndTime_UTC = SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
Where rowid = @rowid

-- return only those that meet the minimum score/weight requirements
Delete FROM @ReturnTable WHERE Score < @MinimumWeight

SELECT * FROM @ReturnTable
--order by Score Desc   

END
```

Comment: Does the method that it mapped the stored procedure to have an out parameter?  Also, try running the following SQL `set fmtonly on exec <storedProcedure> set fmtonly off`.  Pass null as all the parameters.  This should return an empty table with the same structure as a typical result.  If it doesn't, then that is why EF is failing to map your proc.

Comment: Updated question to reflect answers to your question.  Yes when passing null the table structure is displayed empty.

Comment: Did you use the fmtonly option?

Comment: When I run fmtonly it returns an Invalid Object Name on #Person

Comment: If it errors with fmtonly, then EntityFramework will be unable to determine the return type of your proc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on information from cadrell0 and our own tests we found the following:

A stored procedure that is generating a table and returning rows from that table are doing this only at runtime.  When called by Entity Framework with fmtonly it throws an error because the runtime object is not created.

We added FMTONLY OFF to our stored procedure which allowed Entity Framework to see the format of the table and, thus, the format for the complex object.

This allowed me to add the stored procedure, get the correct returned object, and now I'm able to use the sproc to execute our search on the database side of the fence.

This was important to us as the original code is using this and our code HAD to use it.

Comment: I don't recommend leaving that in there.  Now that EF has mapping the stored procedure, you should be able to safely remove it.  Of course, I would recommend you address whatever errors occur when fmtonly is on rather than just disabling it.