# Stored procedure get column information does not return anything?

Tags: entity-framework

I am using entity framework with a stored procedure, in which I am generating query dynamically and executing that query. The stored proc query looks like:

```
Begin
  DECLARE @Query nvarchar(MAX)
  SET @Query = 'SELECT e.id, e.name, e.add, e.phno from employee'
  EXEC sp_executesql @Query
End
```

In above sql code you can see that i am executing `'@Query'` variable, and that variable value can be changed dynamically.

I am able to add my stored proc in my `edmx` file. and then I go to model browser and say  `Add function import` and try to `Get column information` it does not show anything. but when I execute my stored proc at server it returns all columns with values. Why i am not getting column information at model browser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't Entity Framework see my Stored Procedure's column information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996887/why-cant-entity-framework-see-my-stored-procedures-column-information)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` after `BEGIN`.... that supresses messages that might cause it to be "confused"

Answer (score 1):

The model browser isn't running the stored procedure to then gather the column information from its result - it's trying to grab the column information from the underlying procedure definition using the `sys` tables.

This procedure, because it's dynamic, will not have an underlying definition and therefore won't be importable into the EDMX like this.

Comment: thanks..so is there any other way to get column information in model bowser?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know of any way around it.

Answer (score 1):

Temporarily change your stored proc to

```
SELECT TOP 1 e.id, e.name, e.add, e.phno from employee /* ... rest of your proc commented out */
```

Then add it to the EF and create the function import (it will see the columns).

Then change the proc back to how you had it above.