# Error when using "Get Column Information" within Entity Framework 4

Tags: sql, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to use "Get Column Information" within Model Browser but I keep getting this error

An exception of type 'system.io.filenotfoundexception' occurred while attempting to get column information could not load file or assembly microsoft.sqlserver.management.sdk.sfc

[image]

I have Googled this error but with no avail, has anyone has this issue before? is so how did you resolved it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't Entity Framework see my Stored Procedure's column information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996887/why-cant-entity-framework-see-my-stored-procedures-column-information)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently and found this question, with no answer.

I did manage to resolve the issue with the following guide:

http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1113/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-management-sdk-sfc

I suspect this is to do with my machine having SQL Server 2014 installed on it, but Visual Studio expecting 2012 for Edit Function Import.

Hope this helps someone else.