# Can´t get column data on function Imports with Entity Framework 6 and NPGSQL

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework-6, npgsql

We are trying to migrate a web forms (.NET Framework 4.6.1) project from SQL Server to Postgres. The company uses Entity Framework 6 for the creation of database first EDM's.
We used NPGSQL and EntityFramework6.NPGSQL and the NPGSQL PostgreSQL Integration Extension for the creation of the new EDM's. However, when using the Add Function Import tool and trying to get column information for complex types generator, i get the following error:

"An exception of type "System.NotSupportedException" occurred while attempting to get columns information.The exception message is:The specified type is not supported by this selector."

Versions:

NPGSQL 6.0.9
EntityFramework6 6.4.4
EntityFramework6.NPGSQL 6.4.3
NPGSQL PostgreSQL Integration 4.1.12
.NET Framework 4.6.1
PostgreSQL 14.6

We tried modifying postgres functions and sp's to accept null params, based on the Get Column Information operation described on [5996887](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13309133/6198927) but it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

The EF6 provider is no longer being actively maintained, and the Visual Studio integration even less. It's very possible that importing of stored procedures/functions was never implemented - it's very unlikely that this will happen.

I strongly recommend moving to EF Core whenever possible.

Cross-posted as https://github.com/npgsql/EntityFramework6.Npgsql/issues/195#issuecomment-1444601624