# Returning Complex Type from Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

i have stored procedure like this :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CustOrderHist] @CustomerID nchar(5)
AS
SELECT ProductName, Total=SUM(Quantity)
FROM Products P, [Order Details] OD, Orders O, Customers C
WHERE C.CustomerID = @CustomerID
AND C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID AND O.OrderID = OD.OrderID AND OD.ProductID = P.ProductID
GROUP BY ProductName
```

i am adding this SP to my Entity Model. this SP does not returning any table of database so How would i add function import of this and fill my gridview ? Please help

Comment: Duplicate of [Adding stored procedures complex types in Entity-Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833531/adding-stored-procedures-complex-types-in-entity-framework) - see this other SO question (and my answer to it) for a step-by-step explanation of how to do exactly that.

Comment: i just gone through the screenshots you posted on the mentioned thread. but when we access that result how the code would be if columns from multiple tables ?

Comment: You have **one property** on the newly created complex type for each column in the result set - no matter where that column comes from. So in your case, you'd have one property `ProductName` (most likely a string) and a second one `Total` (most likely decimal or int)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: my meant to ask is what will be my code when i consume this resultset?

Comment: You will get back a collection of your new complex type as defined by Entity Framework, with objects that have these two relevant properties set .... I would suggest you **go ahead and try it** to see how it works!

Comment: added the function import and my result name is 'CustOrderHist_Result'. and my method to use that sp is  NorthwindEntities northwind = new NorthwindEntities();

        public CustOrderHist_Result ReturnCust()
        {
            var result = northwind.CustOrderHist("AROUT").ToList();
            return result;     }                                                                     but getting this error : cannot implicitly convert type 'system.collections.Generic.List<modelproj.CustOrderHist_Result>' to 'ModelProj.CustOrderHist_Result'

Comment: solved my problem @marc_s :) ... return type of that function should be List<CustOrderHist_Result> :)