# Entity Framework isn't getting the columns for Complex Type

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, stored-procedures

### The goal

I want to get for my complex types their respective columns.

### The problem

Unlike [this answer, by marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833531/adding-stored-procedures-complex-types-in-entity-framework?answertab=votes#tab-top), in part **(4) (four)**, my complex type have no database columns assigned to him.

To exemplify:

[image: Example]

And before you ask, my function importing is right:

[image: Example 2]

**So, what I have to do?**

### Update 1

I have tried to add manually the properties to my complex type, but it is the best way?

### Update 2

I want to add the scalars properties to my complex type automatically — like in the example I posted before.

Answer (score 2):

@chiefGui I did not understand your question perfectly well, but seems when you click in "Get Column Information" button, you get no columns.

If it's that the problem you can fix it by adding a command in you procedure.

Put a command like this.

```
ALTER PROC ProcName  /* ([,parameters] ) */
AS
BEGIN
    /* this command you make the difference */
    SET FMTONLY OFF

    /* other code here */
END
```

Put this in first line of inside of your procedure. Remove the procedure from EDMX, add again and try again the import. And you'll get all columns returned by your procedure. So de step by step will working well.

If this is not the answer you want please add comment so I can help you.

**EDITED**

This happens because the EF try to getting columns headers without getting a result data. If your procedure has a high level of complexity, the EF will only be able to get the information, if your code is set to check the structure before running.

Comment: I'm using MySQL. Sorry about this — I forget to inform.

Comment: I edited the answer for you to have a better comprehension of the problem. So in my sql i dont know the exact flag, but for you to discover just search for
>> Getting Columns Headers without Result Data

Comment: else you can write your proc without where clause, after import update your proc.

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice that "Not Supported" caption next to the field name? Its because MySql connector can't fails to read datatypes from stored procedure resultset.  This is a bug in MySQL Net Connector since forever.  The work around is a create a table with the same two columns (in your example), import that table before importing the stored procedure into EDMX and when you import your stored procedure, in the Add Function Import dialog box, select "Entities" option instead of complex type, and map to that table.