# Executing Stored Procedures With EF 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I've got an Entity Framework application and a stored procedure I imported that takes one variable of type `varchar`.  I want to get the parameter from a text box control.  The results of the stored procedure I want to set at the data source for a `GridView` control.  However, when I do `dbContext.spMyProc(txtMyField.Text)` I can see with intellisense that the return type of `dbContext.spMyProc(txtMyField.Text)` is int.  I can only assume that it's returning the number of rows in the database.  How can I do `dbContext.storedProc` and set that equal to an IEnumerable type that I can then set as the data source for a `GridView`?

procedure is like

```
select distinct
          pdh.patientId
         ,p.Page
         ,p.Gender
         ,r.Race
from PatientDiagnosisHistory as pdh
inner join.... tables
```

Comment: Do you want to set scalar value as data source? Show your SP for better assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you forgot to map the return type when you are importing the procedure.

On "Add Function Import" screen you must set the entity return or create a new complex type using the columns returned by the procedure.... see this picture of the [screen](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/gg699321.fig12(en-us,MSDN.10).png)

if the procedure return an entity you can use this [tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/execute-stored-procedure-using-dbcontext.aspx) that explain how to do that.

but if you need to create a new complex type using the columns a recommend that you look this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12834237/3203384) for a similar question.