# Model First - Full Text Search Stored Procedure - Returns Int instead of List/IENumerable

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, .net-4.5, entity-framework-6

I have looked for a few days for a solution but can't find one.

I am creating a stored procedure to search a table using fulltext search. I will then combine the result from 15 of these stored procedures into a list ordered by their ranking.

Here is the code for the stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SpAdvancedSearchICAPUsers]
    @searching nvarchar(100) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Set FMTONLY OFF;

    DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVarchar(max)

    IF @searching IS NULL OR @searching = ''
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT (all field names listed separated by commas) FROM Users'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT (all field names listed separated by commas), fts.Rank FROM Users as p JOIN
                    FREETEXTTABLE(Users, (fields to search for listed separated by commas), @searching) 
                    as fts on p.userID = fts.[KEY] WHERE 1=1'
    END

    EXEC @SQLQuery
END
```

I did approached this project doing Model first. I added my stored procedures to my model by right clicking and pressing: `Add New > Function Import...`

I set the name of the function import, selected the stored procedure, selected the "Returns a Collection Of" to Entities: (desired data type the SP returns, in this case, Users).

When I use the stored procedure like this:

```
newSearch.Users = db.SpAdvancedSearchICAPUsers(search); //search is a string
```

`newSearch.Users` is an `IENumerable<Users>`. It says the return type is an int for the stored procedure. I get the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable;

I have also tried adding a parameter definition variable as such right below declaring `@SQLQuery` like this:

```
Declare @ParamDefinition As NVarchar(4000)
```

and then I set it and try and run it like this:

```
Set @ParamDefinition = '@searchingnvarchar(100)'

Exec sp_executesql @SQLQuery, @ParamDefinition, @searching
```

`@searching` is the string which is passed in to search.

I have even tried dragging all of my tables into a DBML file, because I've used stored procedures this way successfully before. When I dragged in the SP to the table I get this message:

[image]

**UPDATE**: Eddie in the comments specified that in the DBML after your drag in the stored procedure, you can set the return type (I chose the User object type). This works. I would rather not do this though. I'll have it as a temporary solution but I have 15 stored procedures I'd have to do that to.

Does anyone know how to get the correct output from the stored procedure using the EDMX file instead of a DBML? When I look at the properties after right clicking in the EDMX and selection "Mapping Details > Stored Procedures / Functions". The return type in the EDMX doesn't have anything. It has no drop downlist, nothing.

[image]

Comment: Did you try setting the return type for the stored procedure in the Properties window? :P Not trying to condescend, but that is what the error says to do and you didn't mention trying it.

Comment: The properties for the stored procedures has no where for me to set the return type. I'm not sure where they are referring to actually set that. I've looked and can't find it anywhere.

Comment: http://riteshkk2000.blogspot.com/2010/08/error-unknown-return-type-return-types.html

Comment: And...I just found it...wow...wow. I literally looked for it everywhere and found it when you mentioned it. Changing the return type by made it so I got a list, which works and THANK YOU for pointing that out and making me look deeper.

Is there any way to do this without using LINQ and DBML though? I'd rather not do that for every single stored procedure I have (there are about 15 of them). This is a good temporary solution but I would like to solve the problem without using LINQ or the DBML file and just use EF6 and my EDMX.

Comment: Please can you elaborate on this?  I've just spent an hour trying to solve this.  In the end, I went for dummy SQL to generate a select statement with the right comments, then commented this out to revert to the correct SQL.  I'm sure your solution would solve my problem, but I don't understand it!

Incidentally, another "solution" which doesn't work is to use an intermediate CTE or temporary table (even with SET FMTONLY OFF added).

Comment: @AndyBrown What part of this issue are you on exactly? If it's the return type, you must go into the Model Browser to change the return type of the stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm hitting the spot here, but if you are doing something like

```
newSearch.Users = db.SpAdvancedSearchICAPUsers(search);
```

and

```
newSearch.Users
```

is of type **User Entity**, then perhaps writing the search statement as

```
    Set @SQLQuery = 'SELECT p.* FROM Users as p JOIN
                     FREETEXTTABLE(Users, (fields to search for listed separated by commas), @searching) 
                     as fts on p.userID = fts.[KEY] WHERE 1=1
                     ORDER BY fts.[Rank]'
```

would work for the simple fact that it is returning the fields a **User Entity** expects (i.e.: no rank field).

To better diagnose whether this is the case or not, the question turns to:

> Does the same problem happen when you send an empty **search** field?

i.e.:

```
newSearch.Users = db.SpAdvancedSearchICAPUsers('');
```

If it works for the latter case, then perhaps the aforementioned change would do.

Please let me know.

Comment: I like your answer and it definitely makes sense. The reason I wanted to return the actual rank is because I will be combining 15 of these stored procedures and ordering them based on the rank that is returning. I have edited my question to include more information.

newSearch.Users is an IENumerable<Users>

When I try and send in an empty string I get the following error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<IcapOrg.Models.Users>'"

I am going to try and do the first suggestion to see if it will, at least, get me the correct return values back.

Comment: Even after I removed fts.Rank as a variable to be returned, it is still giving me an integer.

Comment: If you want to return the _rank_ along with the User fields, you may leave the search query as it was, add a rank field to the non-search query, and then go to your EDMX and double click _SpAdvancedSearchICAPUsers_ under **Basic/Function Imports** on the Model Browser. If you are already associating the returned collection to a Complex Type, then all you need to do is change `newSearch.Users` to be of the same type as the Complex Type being returned by your SP in the EDMX model (which includes the rank) ;)

Comment: When I chose the complex type for "Returns a Collection of" there is nothing in that drop down list. But for some reason when I just RESET it to the Users entity...it is not returning an int anymore. 

So now we solved the problem of not returning an int, but how do I make it return the complex type with the rank when nothing is in that list? Btw, thank you for your help so far. I think were on to it.

Comment: I found this but it doesn't really explain how to get the complex model into that list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456824(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: While you are in the dialog box where you set the return type for the Stored Procedure, if there is nothing in the drop down list to associate it with, have you tried clicking on **Get Column Information** and then on **Create New Complex Type** (both buttons at the bottom of the dialog)?

If you do, then you have effectively created a complex type which you can associate to the SP right away as well as use it later on as a return type in code.

Comment: Yes, I had found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833531/adding-stored-procedures-complex-types-in-entity-framework

And did just as you said and nothing is yet coming up. I'm going to mark this question as answered because you have solved my main issue. Please let me know if you find a different way or what is going wrong with why I can't make the Complex Types. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Most welcome! What do you mean though by "nothing is yet coming up"? Do you mean that no results are coming up, or no issues?

Comment: When I try and add a Complex Type and click the "Create New Complex Type" button, nothing happens. The list of fields in Column Information is also not being populated.

Comment: Oh I see. I'm not totally sure, but the fact that the value being returned by the Stored Procedure comes from an `EXEC @SQLQuery` might be stopping the DB engine from figuring out a proper return schema (since @SQLQuery is a variable). Why not getting rid of the `@SQLQuery` variable altogether and returning one SQL statement from each branch of the `if` statement?