# Entity Framework: Function Import - Code Generated In Designer But Not Recognized By Compiler

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2008, entity-framework-6

Imported a stored procedure into my model following the the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833531/adding-stored-procedures-complex-types-in-entity-framework). The stored procedure and the results class show up in the model browser as well as in the Designer.cs code:

[image: Shown: model browser, and code from the designer.cs class]![enter image description here]Project compiles, but I cannot reference the GetCurrentConfigurationSettings method that was created:

[image: VS does not recognize the new method]

Tried deleting and recreating the function import. Added/removed using statements. I've tried various object/method call permutations, but nothing works.  At wit's end.  What else could I be missing?

Comment: Could you *please* just copy/paste the code? And what *exactly* do you mean by "cannot reference"? If you've got any error messages, please post them.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the resolution to this issue was to delete all the EF related files and start fresh.  The only thing I can think of which might have caused this is that I changed the name of the project that the EF files lived in many times.  I assume this caused some sort of function and/or namespace confusion on EF's (or my own) part. Since recreating the model, I've imported 2 or 3 functions without issue.