# EF ComplexType fields order

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

I'm starting working in EF with C# I'm doing an example where simply I execute a SP and I need to retrieve to a DataGridView.

I add the SP and create a complex type and my SP looks like this

```
select ProductId, ProductName, S.SupplierID, S.CompanyName, 
       C.CategoryID, C.CategoryName, UnitPrice
from dbo.Products P
inner join Suppliers S on S.SupplierID = P.SupplierID
inner join Categories C on C.CategoryID = P.CategoryID
```

But, when I retrieve the data to the DataGridView the Complex type shows the result in a different order, actually it shows like this

```
ProductName, SupplierID, CategoryID (...)
```

So I want to know if there is any chance to modify my complexType and get the output in the same order of my SP?

Comment: Why do you need a stored proc if you're using EF? Query the db directly from LINQ to Entities.

Comment: Well, I think maybe is because at my work (a bank) we still use SP because internal security policy we must not   write database logic in the code only. So thanks for your suggestion but it's not what I was asking. Best regards.

Comment: Ok, then map stored proc output or create a view (if it's allowed). See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456824%28v=vs.100%29.aspx, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833531/adding-stored-procedures-complex-types-in-entity-framework

Comment: Stupid policy anyway, professional development of the security "engineer" made this decision stopped somewhere in 1998,

Comment: Also you may want to try another ORM such as [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) because using EF with SP you're loosing the most power and features of it.

Answer (score 0):

Create and map the types in Entity Framework:

```
class Product
{
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public double UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

class Supplier
{
    public Guid SupplierID { get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
}

class Category 
{
    public Guid CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

Then query your database:

```
var q = from p in db.Products
        select new
        {
            p.ProductId, p.ProductName, p.UnitPrice,
            p.Supplier.SupplierID, p.Supplier.CompanyName, 
            p.Category.CategoryID, p.Category.CategoryName, 
        };
```

Then bind it onto the control:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = q.ToArray();
```