# Get returned value marked by RETURN from SP in Entity Framework C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

The problem is that many Stored Procedure must be return status code.
Which marked as

```
RETURN @status
```

so the EF (6.x) didn't recognize return type and SP call returns modified rows count (e.g 1,2 etc.)

***The workaround to replace RETURN to SELECT is impossible***

***Change EF call to ADO.NET IMPOSSIBLE***

So there is any workaround to get right value from SP without modifying SP

Comment: also trying to chage function import setting return type Int32 getting error The data reader returned by the store data provider does not have enough columns for the query requested.
And the link below shows the same answer

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c4b85efc-a381-4595-8ae9-185378e4ef17/the-data-reader-returned-by-the-store-data-provider-does-not-have-enough-columns-for-the-query?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Comment: @SeanLange what?

Comment: As posted this question doesn't make any sense to me at all. What are you trying to do?

Comment: i have Stored Procedure which must return status codes. but in stored procedure it written like this RETURN @status. in C# code Entity framework doesn't recognize RETURN statement and returns modified row count. I want to get rigth value returned by SP

Comment: please remove duplicate mark

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are using database approach. From the designer you can specify the return type of the stored procedure. Refer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833531/adding-stored-procedures-complex-types-in-entity-framework) for more details how to do that.

Keep in mind that you wont need `return` part, just put in there `select @status`

Comment: The workaround to replace RETURN to SELECT is impossible - this is marked in question!

Comment: Is it possible to create another procedure as a wrapper procedure which will have the select part so you could have something like this `CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc_example]
(
 @id int
)    
AS                                                                
BEGIN
DECLARE @ReturnValue INT
EXEC @ReturnValue = CallAnotherProc @id
SELECT @ReturnValue;
END` otherwise you have to use `Database.SqlQuery<int>(query)` syntax

Comment: no I can't database is inaccessible for modifying or adding new ones

Comment: hmmm then stick to `ADO.NET`, this is the best option I guess in your circumstances